# How to set proxy details to NSURLDownload object

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, proxy, cfnetwork

I am creating a downloader, which I want to run through a specific proxy server. I am able to pass the proxy information to the CFURLRef object. But not able to use the same with NSURLDownload which will completely ignore the proxy settings made.

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"urlstring"];

CFReadStreamRef readStream; 
CFHTTPMessageRef message = CFHTTPMessageCreateRequest(kCFAllocatorDefault,
CFSTR("GET"),
(CFURLRef)url,
kCFHTTPVersion1_1);
readStream = CFReadStreamCreateForHTTPRequest(kCFAllocatorDefault, message);
CFTypeRef keys[2], values[2];
keys[0] = kCFStreamPropertyHTTPSProxyHost;
values[0] = @"proxy.host";
keys[1] = kCFStreamPropertyHTTPSProxyPort;
values[1] = CFNumberCreate(NULL, kCFNumberSInt32Type, @"portNo");
CFDictionaryRef proxyDict = CFDictionaryCreate(NULL, keys, values, 2, &kCFTypeDictionaryKeyCallBacks, &kCFTypeDictionaryValueCallBacks);
// boRet =
 CFReadStreamSetProperty(readStream, kCFStreamPropertyHTTPProxy, proxyDict);

CFNetworkCopyProxiesForURL(
   CFURLRef          url,
   CFDictionaryRef   proxySettings
);
```

Now if i convert CFURLRef to NSURL object and pass the same to downloader, it doesn't work as expected.
How can I pass the properties set to CFURLRef object to NSURLRequest?..Is there any other approach to accomplish this?..I also tried using ASIHTTPRequest wrapper..but how can this be converted into NSURLRequest?..Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks